# Разрушение объекта на мелкие части в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким способом можно разрушить объект на мелкие частицы? С помощью Particle System как примерно это сделать? Например, чтоб рассыпался 2д квадрат

Comment: не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться и причем тут Particle System? вы хотите сделать анимацию? или хотите разбить Mesh на части? приведите пример - картинки или видео того, что вам нужно.

Comment: есть обычный 2д куб(квадрат). Надо, чтобы при уничтожении он рассыпался на мелкие части, а не просто исчез, каким способом это лучше сделать?

Comment: Если после этого частицы не взаимодействуют с игровым процессом, то, думаю, обычной анимации достаточно.